# pip --version command show error, how to fix it?

Tags: python, pip

I am using MacOS Mojave.

I installed `python` using brew command. And before i could use both `pip --version`, and `pip3 --version`. I saw that i had previous version of `pip`. I ran the command `pip install --upgrade pip`.  When i run `python --version` its how me the version. When i run `pip3 --version` i get this:

```
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

But when i run `pip --version` , its gives me error:

```
pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 19.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==19.1.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How can i fix this? I tried to run `brew doctor` and tried to find any solution with no luck.

I have this in my `zshrc` file: 
`# Python version from Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

When i type `which python` i get following: `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you:)

Comment: did you check out [this link][https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6399]

Comment: The link you gave me, it was nothing there? No issue?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6399

Comment: Thank you, seem to be an issue with Homebrew way of installing python.

Comment: the link given does not fix the issue.